# Null Reference Exception - even when new key word is present

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-api

The following is the code :

```
            Dim x As New Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee
            x.Email = "xxccxxxxx@gmail.com"
            x.DisplayName = "xxxxx"
            x.ResponseStatus = "Aproveed"
            Dim y As New Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee
            y.Email = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
            y.DisplayName = "suji"
            y.ResponseStatus = "Aproveed"
            Dim attndList As New List(Of EventAttendee)
            attndList.Add(x)
            attndList.Add(y)
            Dim googleCalendarEvent As New [Event]()
            googleCalendarEvent.Attendees.Add(y)'<--- throws exception here
            googleCalendarEvent.Attendees.Add(x)
```

Exception details: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. why this is happening? how can i overcome this?

**Updates**
when i use like:

```
 Dim googleCalendarEvent As New [Event]()
  googleCalendarEvent.Attendees = New EventAttendee()
```

it shows the error as

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee]'.

Comment: @ Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå  : is it your job? check whether that link you provided answer for my question?

Comment: Yes. And the duplicate is correct. The property `Attendees` is not instantiated. You need to create a new instance. `googleCalendarEvent.Attendees = New List(Of EventAttendee)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim x As New Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee
            x.Email = "xxccxxxxx@gmail.com"
            x.DisplayName = "xxxxx"
            x.ResponseStatus = "Aproveed"
            Dim y As New Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee
            y.Email = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
            y.DisplayName = "suji"
            y.ResponseStatus = "Aproveed"
            Dim attndList As New List(Of EventAttendee)
            attndList.Add(x)
            attndList.Add(y)
            Dim googleCalendarEvent As New [Event]()
            googleCalendarEvent.Attendees = attndList
```

if you want to assign new list then do following thing.

```
    Dim googleCalendarEvent As New Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.[Event]()
    googleCalendarEvent.Attendees = New List(Of EventAttendee)
    googleCalendarEvent.Attendees.Add(y)
    googleCalendarEvent.Attendees.Add(x)
```

Comment: it will thrown error as : `Unable to cast object of type 'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee]'.`